# Helical - Worm Drive

Tags: gears

Is it possible to have a helical gear and a worm gear with the teeth angled the same amount, so that the helical gear can drive the worm gear, unlike a spur gear.

Can the helical gear also move the worm gear along the axle like a gear rack. until the worm gear is stopped and then it resumes driving the worm gear normally.

This is to make an OR gate, I can show an example using Lego Technic gears here:
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. You are asking if you can build something that you have already built a Lego model of.

Comment: Are you asking if using a helical gear will prevent the set from locking up when using the gear to drive the worm?

Comment: @TrevorArchibald Yes, as spur gears cannot drive worm gears unless you use the worm as a gear rack.

Comment: @RecycleBin That can be the case but it's not universally true. If the coefficient of friction is low or the lead angle is high, the worm and gear may not be self-locking.

Comment: I could technically use two helicals in perpendicular to get the same effect, the bottom helical will have to be able to mesh with the axle yet be shifted across from side to side. it is sort of the same thing as a worm gear I suppose

Comment: I am also unclear on what you are asking. And like Trevor mentioned; worm drives can and do backspin especially when already in motion. Maybe you should look into a one way clutch. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprag_clutch

Comment: If both inputs are spun then one goes to nothing however the other one drives the worm gear,  if you change the motor direction it shifts the worm gear to the other input therefore that one is the driver.

Comment: if no inputs are spun then the result is a 0 and if only one input is spun in the right direction then the output is a 1